# Why is my jsondata object undefined?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, javascript-objects

```
var jsondata = $.parseJSON('{"bwpaperback":{"creme":{"5x8":[".95",".016"],"5_25x8":[".95",".016"],"5_5x8_5":[".95",".016"],"6x9":[".95",".016"],"pages":["18","1050"]},"white":{"5x8":[".95",".016"],"5_25x8":[".95",".016"],"5_5x8_5":[".95",".016"],"6x9":[".95",".016"],"8x8":[".95",".016"],"8_5x8_5":[".95",".016"],"7x10":["1.35",".021"],"8x10":["1.35",".021"],"8_25x11":["1.35",".021"],"8_5x11":["1.35",".021"],"pages":["18","1200"]}},"bwhardcover":{"case":{"creme":{"5x8":["6.05",".016"],"5_5x8_5":["6.05",".016"],"6x9":["6.05",".016"],"pages":["18","1050"]},"white":{"5x8":["6.05",".016"],"5_5x8_5":["6.05",".016"],"6x9":["6.05",".016"],"8x8":["6.05",".016"],"8_5x8_5":["6.05",".016"],"7x10":["6.05",".021"],"8x10":["6.05",".021"],"8_5x11":["6.05",".021"],"pages":["18","1200"]}},"cloth":{"creme":{"5_5x8_5":["6.05",".016"],"6x9":["6.05",".016"],"pages":["18","1050"]},"white":{"5x8":["6.05",".016"],"5_5x8_5":["6.05",".016"],"6x9":["6.05",".016"],"pages":["18","1200"]}}},"scpaperback":{"5x7":[".95",".026"],"5x8":[".95",".026"],"5_25x8":[".95",".026"],"5_5x8_5":[".95",".026"],"6x9":[".95",".026"],"8_5x8)5":[".95",".026"],"7x10":["1.30",".031"],"8x10":["1.30",".031"],"8_25x11":["1.30",".031"],"8_5x11":["1.30",".031"],"pages":["18","1200"]},"schardcover":{"case":{"5x8":["6.05",".026"],"5_5x8_5":["6.05",".026"],"6x9":["6.05",".026"],"8x8":["6.05",".026"],"8_5x8_5":["6.05",".026"],"7x10":["6.05",".031"],"8x10":["6.05",".031"],"8.5x11":["6.05",".031"],"pages":["18","1200"]},"cloth":{"5x8":["6.05",".026"],"5_5x8_5":["6.05",".026"],"6x9":["6.05",".026"],"pages":["18","1200"]}},"pcpaperback":{"5_5x8_5":["1.05",".06"],"6x9":["1.05",".09"],"8x8":["1.05",".09"],"8_5x8_5":["1.05",".09"],"7x10":["1.55",".10"],"8x10":["1.55",".10"],"8_5x11":["1.55",".10"],"pages":["4,900"]},"pchardcover":{"case":{"5x8":["6.05",".06"],"5_5x8_5":["6.05",".06"],"6x9":["6.05",".091"],"8x8":["6.05",".091"],"8_5x8_5":["6.05",".091"],"7x10":["6.05",".011"],"8x10":["6.05",".011"],"8_5x11":["6.05",".011"],"pages":["24,840"]},"cloth":{"5x8":["6.05",".06"],"5_5x8_5":["6.05",".06"],"6x9":["6.05",".091"],"pages":["24,840"]}}}');

        if(main.hasClass('bw') && main.hasClass('paperback')){
            baseprice = jsondata[calctype][color][size][0];
            perpage = jsondata[calctype][color][size][1];
            minpages = jsondata[calctype][color].pages[0];
            maxpages = jsondata[calctype][color].pages[1];
        }
```

I'm not sure if I need to provde more code. but it says "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '#' of undefined"

This worked when I was using $.getJSON from an external json file. How can I use this as a object instead of .json?

thanks!

Comment: Your code looks fine. Can you tell us, what is the value of `main`, `calctype`, `color`, `size`?

Comment: var main = $('#compcalc');

Comment: calctype color and size are all based on selected settings from radio buttons. this should be working, because like I said it was working when I was using the .json file. but I can't get the object to work for some reason

Comment: did u used ajax for fetching the data from json file??

Comment: I used $.getJSON() which is shorthand for $.ajax so I believe that's how that works.

Comment: In [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gdvex0ww/) it works just fine.

Comment: WTH do you use a JSON string instead of an object literal? Btw, none of your objects has a `#` property, so you might want to check the values of `calctype` and `color` first.

Comment: What @Bergi said (WTH indeed), plus: You appear to handle some floats as strings, which may also lead to problems.